# Crash when deleting a pointer in a loop and accessing the next element

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an array containing bullet class pointers and QList containing  QGraphicsItem class pointers ... Bullet derives from QGraphicsItem. I iterate through QList and check if QGrapjicsItem* is the same as one in Bullet* array.. if it is i delete item. The problem is, in the next iteration of the loop, when i want to acces next item in the QList - it crashes (segmentation fault) - someone knows what may be the reason of it?

```
void PlayerDefences::checkCollisions(QGraphicsItem* item)
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> itemsCollideWithShip = item->collidingItems();  
    std::vector<Bullet*>* bullets = Level1::getBulletContainer();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCollideWithShip.size(); i++) {
        try {
            if(itemsCollideWithShip[i]==nullptr) continue;
            if(Bullet* d = dynamic_cast<Bullet*>(itemsCollideWithShip[i]); d != nullptr ){  
                bullets->erase(std::remove(bullets->begin(), bullets->end(), d), bullets->end());
                Game::getScene()->removeItem(d);
                delete d;
                d = nullptr; 
            }
        } catch (const std::bad_cast& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
 
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my full stack trace dump:

```
1  libstdc++-6!.dynamic_cast                                                                                                                                            0x7ffa3b1402f2 
2  PlayerDefences::checkCollisions                                                                                                               playerdefences.cpp 47  0x7ff7e0fb651b 
3  Player::advance                                                                                                                               player.cpp         97  0x7ff7e0fb554c 
4  Level1::advance                                                                                                                               level1.cpp         102 0x7ff7e0fb4532 
5  QtPrivate::FunctorCall<QtPrivate::IndexesList<>, QtPrivate::List<>, void, void (Level1:: *)()>::call(void (Level1:: *)(), Level1 *, void * *) qobjectdefs_impl.h 152 0x7ff7e0fbcdb9 
6  QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<void (Level1:: *)()>::call<QtPrivate::List<>, void>(void (Level1:: *)(), Level1 *, void * *)                       qobjectdefs_impl.h 185 0x7ff7e0fbda8c 
7  QtPrivate::QSlotObject<void (Level1:: *)(), QtPrivate::List<>, void>::impl(int, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase *, QObject *, void * *, bool *)    qobjectdefs_impl.h 395 0x7ff7e0fbcfba 
8  QMimeType::filterString() const                                                                                                                                      0x7ffa37bb9357 
9  QTimer::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)                                                                                                                                    0x7ffa37948a9a 
10 QObject::event(QEvent *)                                                                                                                                             0x7ffa3792b3b7 
11 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                              0x7ffa36955946 
12 QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                                     0x7ffa378f6ed8 
13 QEventDispatcherWin32Private::sendTimerEvent(int)                                                                                                                    0x7ffa37a69f2f 
14 QEventDispatcherWin32::event(QEvent *)                                                                                                                               0x7ffa37a6f700 
15 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                              0x7ffa36955946 
16 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                               0x7ffa378f69ed 
17 QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject *, int, QThreadData *)                                                                                             0x7ffa378fa3a9 
18 QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::sendPostedEvents()                                                                                                                       0x7ffa37329e6e 
19 QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)                                                                                          0x7ffa37a6e9f0 
20 QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)                                                                                     0x7ffa37329e55 
21 QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)                                                                                                              0x7ffa37900fd3 
22 QCoreApplication::exec()                                                                                                                                             0x7ffa378ff8b6 
23 main                                                                                                                                          main.cpp           9   0x7ff7e0fb4c62
```

Comment: Probably a dangling pointer.  `d` is set to nullptr, but is `itemsCollideWithShip[i]` set to nullptr?

Comment: No, itemsCollideWithShip contains all the bullets that currently collide with the ship, its returned by QGraphicsItem::collidingItems().